# Opening a program in powershell and getting its handle

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a script that will open Firefox and get the window's handle for further use. But my problem is that the browser window that opens has the same "title" to other windows already running so i cannot filter the list of handles by that... Is there any way to either "Tag" the window at startup or to get the handle trough other means?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) with the `-PassThru` switch parameter, e.g. `Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru`. Then you get some output as below.

```
   Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)   Id  SI ProcessName
  --------  ------    -----      -----     ------   --  -- -----------
     236      14      3100      13072       0,03   5004  11 notepad
```

From the linked Start-Process help page:

> Returns a process object for each process that the cmdlet started. By default, this cmdlet does not generate any output.

You can compose Start-Process with [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Process?view=powershell-7.1) as follows to get the *MainWindowHandle*:

```
$proc = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru
(Get-Process -Id $proc.Id).MainWindowHandle
```

Comment: Adding to Tomek's fine answer. If the process you launch, starts an executable that starts a bunch of other process then dies (kind of like Chrome.exe). You'll need a different approach. Also, I think there is a `MainWindowHandle` property in the process object returned by `Start-Process`.

Comment: @Adam - yes, You are right, basically both `start-process` and `get-process` return System.Diagnostics.Process Object so both would have this `MainWindowHandle` property